# Compute the order of a special group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

If we define $ G $ to be $ \langle a,b,c,d \ \ | \ \ a^2=b^2=c^2=d^2=1, (ab)^3=(bc)^4=(cd)^3=1, ac=ca,ad=da,bd=db \rangle $, then what's the order of $ G $?

When $ G $ has only two generators, the problem of this type is ok for me. I just need to 'guess' all distinct elements of $ G $ and verify the conjecture. However, in this problem, I have no idea about elements of $ G $ :(

I also try to find the index of $ H :=\langle  a,b,c \ \ | \ \ a^2=b^2=c^2=1, (ab)^3=(bc)^4, ac=ca \rangle $ because I know the order of $ H $. But I still failed. Any hints?

Comment: TeX note: \langle and \rangle look better in this context than < and > (I edited).

Comment: Both $G$ and $H$ are infinite. Have you missed out some relations?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a problem. I edit the post.

Comment: With the edits it is clear that your groups $G$ and $H$ are the Coxeter groups $F_4$ and $B_3$. The order of $F_4$ is known to be $1152$, while the order of $B_3$ is known to be $48$. ($B_3$ has index $24$ in $F_4$.)

Comment: How to get $ B_3 $ has index $ 24 $ in $ F4 $? It seems non-trivial.

Comment: You can either use known results about the finite Coxeter groups, or you could do it on a computer using coset enumeration. You still have the presentation of $H$ wrong. It should be $(ab)^3=(bc)^4=1$. Also, theoretically, proving that $|G:H|| =24$ would only tell you that $|G| \le 1152$.